# Jenkins SVN using https protocol

Tags: svn, https, jenkins

Hi I am having problem connecting my jenkins SVN with https protocol. I can access other SVN repository with http protocol but not with https. For some reason, my svn repo must use https;

I can't seem to find solution on how can jenkins  checkout/update from the repository.
The errors is something like this

```
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:291)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:276)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:264)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:516)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:98)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1001)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:178)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the HTTP server - serving the SVN repository - using self-signed certificate or some custom-provided cert? It might not be in global certs file.

Comment: Is there an option to log into the server which drives Jenkins, and try there e.g. `svn log <HTTPS-URL for your repo>`? As a result, you will be asked for accepting the certificate (if that was the error), and Jenkins may then use SVN accordingly.

Comment: Make sure your repository is not authenticated using Kerberos. If it is, [see this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin+HTTPS+Kerberos+authentication).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Hi Lukasz, i am not yet familiar about the certificates thingy.. If it is not in the global certs file, how can i put it there?

Comment: hi @mliebelt, I installed the XShell plugin in Jenkins so that i can run 'svn log <url>' in commandline. When i look the console output of the build, it says something like this `Error validating server certificate for
 -The certificate is no.
Certificate information:
 -Hostname:subversion
 -Issuer:sample
 - Fingerprint: a4;a5;
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? svn: OPTIONS of `. how can i accept the certiface permanently? how can i press 'p' using XShell? I think if jenkins can accept it permanently, then i can now connect to the svn with https protocol. any suggestions?

Comment: Continuation... using XShell i put this command `svn log <url> --trust-server-cert --non-interactive` , still no luck when connecting/checkout/update from svn...

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem once, as @milebelt wrote above, try to connect to the SVN server from within the machine jenkins runs on (with the same user jenkins runs as) with a SVN client (you must install one if it's not installed, though many distros come with one preinstalled)

This will create a certificate and keys under `~/.svn` (the defauly folder) if i remember correctly.

Later when you run the build from Jenkins, it will use the key the svn client created before to authenticate.